# Should I use 301 for in-site redirects?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, localization, geolocation, http-status-code-301

We would like to redirect to a localized version of our entry webpage if IP is detected to be from a certain country. We are using ASP.Net, [GeoLite Country Db](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) (it's a very small, 1Mb downloadable DB at time of writing this question).

So, most users would get english content, but if they come from a local place, they would have local content served by default. Of course, they would be able to change the preferred language at any time.

**The question is:** if `www.example.com` by default displays `default.aspx`, should we (if we detect the IP to be "local"):

1. Use `"301 Moved Permanently"` and redirect it to, say, `www.example.com/local.aspx`, **or**
2. Simply render the appropriate content inside `default.aspx`?

We would like to know if there are some side effects with SEO or similar issues with any of the approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just deliver the localized contents of *local.aspx* and send an appropriate [*Content-Location*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.14) referring to *local.aspx* along with it.

Or, if you want a redirect, use the status code 307 to indicate a temporary redirect.

Comment: 307 seemed appropriate to me also, however HTTP/1.0 agents won't recognize it. I will probably render it. Should I use `Server.Execute` or is there another way?

Comment: @Groo: You could reply with a 302 in that case.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best solution.

From wikipedia it says to use 300 for different languages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.1

> The HTTP standard defines several
>   status codes for redirection:
>
> ```
> * 300 multiple choices (e.g. offer different languages)
> * 301 moved permanently
> * 302 found (originally temporary redirect, but now commonly used to specify redirection for unspecified reason)
> * 303 see other (e.g. for results of cgi-scripts)
> * 307 temporary redirect
> ```

Comment: in the docs it says "If the server has a preferred choice of representation, it SHOULD include the specific URI for that representation in the Location field; user agents MAY use the Location field value for automatic redirection. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise."

Comment: But the negotiation does not fail in this case. So using 300 is not appropriate.

Comment: And what about 307? Would it serve better than 301 in this case?